# Angular2 - sum the values of a property in the Object sent from an observerable

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

in my **service.component.j**s I return an observable of an array of Student from the http call. Student object has a property called age,

student.ts

```
export class Student {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  age:number;
}
```

service.componnet.js

```
getStudents (): Observable< Student[]>
```

In the **studentManagement.component.ts** which is an observer to the observable above, I want to sum the age of the students. I know I can put a sum() in source (which is less preferred, as I also need to display other info of the Students in the page, such as id, name ,individual age as well.) or calculate it from _studentList. Besides these two, any other way?

```
private _studentList:Student[]=[];

    .subscribe(
            returnedStudents => {
              console.log(returnedStudents);
              this._studentList = returnedStudents;
            },
            erroMsg => this._errorMessage = erroMsg
          )
```

Comment: Could you please add more code. I don't see what you want to sum and what result you want to get besides the sum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `map` on the Observable to return the sum.

```
getStudents().map(arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b.age, 0));
```

Here we reduce the inner Array to the sum of the age property of the students. Now what we have is a `Observable<number>`, which will emit the sum of the ages.

If you want to display both:

```
getStudents (): Observable< Student[]> {
   return this.http.get(/*...*/).share();
}

getAgeSum(): Observable<number> {
    return this.studentsObservable
       .map(arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b.age, 0));
}
```

We have to call share here, so that the Observable becomes hot and doesn't do the HTTP Request twice.

Comment: Is there a solution that calls getStudents() once to display all the students, as well as sum the age?

Comment: Sure, just wrap the above code in a different function and call `share()` on the original Observable. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `map` function that returns both student list and age sums. Something like that:

```
studentsObservable.map((students) => {
  return {
    ages: this.getAge(students),
    students: students
  };
});
```